# PHPMailer отправка большого количества писем

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Стоит задача отправить около 3000 писем на разные e-mail адреса с общим текстом и разными ссылками в теле письма. Я использую PHPMailer, который читает excel файл и в цикле перебирает строки. В этом же цикле я планирую отправлять письма. Однако при тестировании столкнулся со следующей проблемой: я беру файл с 200 адресами и отправляю сам себе эти 200 писем. Примерно по 50 письма часть писем перестает доходить до меня, а $mail->send() - возвращает ошибку. Пробовал ставить задержку в цикле 1, 3 и 5 секунд - сталкивался с такой же проблемой.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда смотреть? Какие-то ограничения на нашем хостинге или в настройках сервера? Может ли чем-то помочь запуск скрипта кроном?

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, код ошибки которая возвращается при выполнении скрипта

Comment: Скрипт выполняется корректно, однако не все письма отправляются - if(!$mail->send())

Comment: Цитирую: Примерно по 50 письма часть писем перестает доходить до меня, а $mail->send() - возвращает ошибку. Какую ошибку?

Comment: Проверяю следующим образом: if(!$mail->send()). Как получить именно код ошибки у данной функции - не знаю.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php Вывод через echo. Укажите только код ошибки

Comment: Скорее всего у вас код ```429``` много запросов в определенный промежуток времени, детали: https://httpstatuses.com/429

Comment: Сервис который отправляет письма может иметь ограничения, и попросить дополнительную плату. (Только догадка) Жду код ошибки)

Comment: Извините, кажется я не очень понимаю как её отследить. Попробовал try {
            $mail->send();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        } 

Но результата нет.

Comment: Код: 
try {
            $mail->send();
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            echo $e->getCode() . ' ' . $e->errorMessage() . '<br>';
        }
также не выводит никаких сообщений.

Comment: На текущий момент смог получить следующую ошибку: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: mail@domain.ru: The recipient has exceeded message rate limit. Try again later.

Comment: Сама ошибка говорит вам о Вашей проблеме. Попробуйте найти  домен который не имеет лимитов на отправку

Comment: В общем-то да. Так как отправка писем будет разовой - планирую отправлять с интервалом по времени.  Большое спасибо за участие!